# save subset of dom for later use preserve eventlisteners and values entered

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello Guys is there any method I can save a part (subtree) of the DOM for later use?

What I want to achieve is the following:

I create a two forms with pure javascript.

```
form1 = document.createElement('form1');
input = document.createElement('input');
input.addEventListener(Listener);
form1.appendChild('input');
....
```

The forms are build the same way.

Somewhere I have a div in my page whereto I appendChild('form1');

Suppose I have also a button on my page. The button should switch between the forms. So when I push it I want to SAVE THE STATE OF form1 (I want to keep the eventlisteners attached and also the texts that the user entered in input fields) for example in a variable and remove(detach) after the form1 from the DOM and bind form2.

I know this could be solved with css and toggle the forms by making one hidden and the other visible but I'm in fact interested in saving the subtree of the DOM as a snapshot.

I hope you understand my question since English is not my native language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can attach the form to a [*document fragment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and replace it with the other form, and vice versa.

Comment: That's what I have at this moment but I cant preserve state and I don't know to get the form back in a fragment for later rerender. The documentation says this: "A common use for DocumentFragment is to create one, assemble a DOM subtree within it, then append or insert the fragment into the DOM using Node interface methods such as appendChild() or insertBefore()). Doing this moves the fragment's nodes into the DOM, leaving behind an empty DocumentFragment. ...."

Comment: How can I get the Form back in some structure? Form should preserve state of inputs that means for me if a user entered some text in an input field i want that to be stored as it was at the moment i decide to get the form back in the structure (maybe document fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The button should switch between the forms. So when I push it I want
>   to SAVE THE STATE OF form1 (I want to keep the eventlisteners attached
>   and also the texts that the user entered in input fields)

The `createElement` creates an element and returns it as a reference which you store in a variable. Note that this is a live reference. You could take advantage of that in this use-case.

> **Caution**: Do NOT use this on production. This is not recommended. Use simple UI/UX elements to show/hide parts of your page by way of
>   CSS and/or Javascript. The example below is solely to demonstrate the way things work.

Store the references to your forms in variables. Use `appendChild` to add those to your container. Overwrite `innerHTML` to remove the element from the container, and use `appendChild` again to swap with the other variable. All event handlers, and the input element states will be saved as-is, because of the variable being a reference.

**Example:** (*Type different values in inputs to see state while switching.*)

```js
var forms = [], 
    btn = document.getElementById('btn'), 
    display = document.getElementById('display'), 
    result = document.getElementById('result'), 
    currentForm = 0;
;

start();

function start() {
  btn.addEventListener('click', switcher);
  forms[0] = createForm(0);
  forms[1] = createForm(1);
  display.appendChild(forms[0]);
}

function switcher() { 
  display.innerHTML = '';
  if (currentForm === 0) {
    display.appendChild(forms[++currentForm]);
  } else {
    display.appendChild(forms[--currentForm]);
  }
}

function createForm(idx) { 
  var frm, inp, lbl;
  frm = document.createElement('form');
  inp = document.createElement('input');
  inp.addEventListener('input', show);
  lbl = document.createElement('label');
  lbl.textContent = "Form # " + (idx + 1) + ": ";
  frm.appendChild(lbl);
  frm.appendChild(inp);
  return frm;
}

function show(e) { result.textContent = e.target.value; }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Switch</button>
<hr>
<div id="display"></div>
<hr>
<span>Keeping typing in the input above: </span><span id="result"></span>
```

---

As mentioned before, use [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) for storing the fragments which you can refer later.

Comment: yep, and the reason for NOT to use this approach on production are memory leaks?

Comment: I know about this approach, I also wrote in the question that I'm not interested in hiding showing forms I want to store them somehow for later use. In fact I'm interested in cloning somehow a subtree of the DOM

Comment: @panwork cloning is no problem itself - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode (be aware of course about ID reduplications) and for storing use localStorage

Comment: I don't get it @panwork? You only wrote "*The button should switch between the forms*", and now you say that you are not interested in hiding / showing forms!?!? If you wanted to know about cloning, then you should have written that in your question clearly. Nowhere in your question is cloning mentioned. Further, this answer demonstrates to you that as long as reference is saved in the variable, the state is also saved. You have your form stored for later use. Now what really is your problem? Please decide that first.

Comment: I don't know how to call it if its cloning or save the state of the dom or something else. What I want to achieve is to save a part of the DOM as it is at a given moment with all the listeners and the changes that a user does to the elements. I'm thinking of the DOM as a Tree in each node resides a DOMElement. I can build another Tree with DOMElements with document fragment thats clear to me than I can add that to the document with appendChild thats also clear. What I want is to get back anyhow that fragment that I insertet to the DOM with the changes the user did on it. The fragment is a Form

Comment: I wrote also in the question this "I know this could be solved with css and toggle the forms by making one hidden and the other visible but I'm in fact interested in saving the subtree of the DOM as a snapshot."

Comment: I was also looking at https://api.jquery.com/detach/ and this is the most similar thing to what i want to do. So we can call it also detach and it should work as if you take one node away from the DOM with all its Children granchildren up to the leaves keeping them somewhere in Memory or Probably on disk and at any given time later I should be able to attach them back to the DOM.

Comment: @panwork: That is exactly what the example in my answer shows! Did you even read the code? Ok, I created a simpler example for you. Go through this carefully - https://jsfiddle.net/Ly91na3q/. Notice the switcher function. It does exactly what you describe. It saves the form in a variable, and empties the display div. When it is added back, see that the event handlers, and state are all restored.

Comment: I'm sorry! You are right as I described the problem you gave the right answer and it's working. I read last night a more about the DOM and I have understood that you only get references to the Objects in it you have also access to the objects only by means of the API. So if you want to store a subtree of that you have to build your own objects and store those with a 1 to 1 relationship. I will also taking your answer as correct. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the [Document.createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) is not too suitable in your case because you need to keep changes after the fragmented piece of document will be inserted into the renderer (into the "real" page's DOM)?
If so, then you could try to use experimental [createHTMLDocument()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) and store it somewhere (in localStorage for example) what gives you the ability to synchronise both documents - your "real" one and it's copy.
But actually this question includes also avoiding superfluous repaint/reflow etc so it is a good moment to dive into documentation ;)

Comment: I am using document.createDocumentFragment(), in fact I have more document Fragments. Now what I want is to add this fragment to the DOM what I also do with appendChild(). But after the user adds text to the input elements I want to backup anyhow from the DOM the fragment that I added before. My fragment has eventListeners also added to different Elements. I can't find any function like getDocumentFragment(). The only function I could use is document.getElementById() like that i keep a reference to the top element of the tree I am interested at